# How to automatically apply a category based on the post title?

Tags: posts, categories

I have a Wordpress site talking about laptop review. In every post, I always add a category name on the title.

For example "ASUS ZenBook UX480FD Review" is categorized as "ASUS".

However, I need to add the category manually. For efficiency purpose, I want my site to automatically apply category based on the post title (especially the first word of the title).

Is anybody knows the plugin or code to do so?

Thanks!

note: the category slug already created

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. I havn't really tested it, so I'm not sure it works - might require some small tweaks aswell.

```
function add_category_based_on_title( $post_id ) {

    // title
    $title = get_the_title( $post_id );

    // get first part of title
    $substr = explode( " ", $title )[0];

    // get category id
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( $substr ); 

    // check category
    if ( ! empty( $category_id ) ) ) {

        // set category
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, [ $category_id ], true )

    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_category_based_on_title' );
```

References:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

Comment: I would add some conditions to that. For example check if the post is not a revision...

Comment: I received a syntax error at the line "add_action( 'save_post', 'add_category_based_on_title' );" (without quote mark)

not sure which one I should edit